# How to apply Jinja `length` logic to nested JSON array?

Tags: html, json, jinja2

Riffing on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052910/how-to-access-nested-json-with-jinja/72060588#72060584), how do I drill even further into an nested array and apply some `length` logic?

**Goal:** If the `PositionsHeld` array has more than 1 entry, I want to separate the values with a comma `,` **but not for the last entry**.

**Example:**

**JSON snippet:**

```
{
    "Employers": [
        {
            "EmploymentType": "Food Service",
            "Employer": "Test Brew",
            "EmployerURL": "",
            "StartMonth": 9,
            "StartYear": 2020,
            "EndMonth": null,
            "EndYear": null,
            "City": "Olympia",
            "State": "WA",
            "PositionsHeld": [
                {"Position": "Barista"},
                {"Position": "Asst. Manager"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "EmploymentType": "Food Service",
            "Employer": "The Steakhouse",
            "EmployerURL": "https://www.steakmill.com/",
            "StartMonth": 7,
            "StartYear": 2019,
            "EndMonth": 1,
            "EndYear": 2020,
            "City": "Milton",
            "State": "WA",
            "PositionsHeld": [
                {"Position": "Busser"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML w/Jinja snippet:**

```
{% for e in data.Employers %}

<h3>
{% for p in e.PositionsHeld %} 
    {% if p|length > 1 %}     <-- Here is the crux of question -->
        {{ p.Position }} ,    <-- Want to add a "," if needed BUT NOT TO THE FINAL POSITION-->
        else {{ p.Position }} 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
</h3>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for with this:

```
{% for e in data.Employers %}
    <h3>
        {% for p in e.PositionsHeld %}
            {% if not loop.last %}{{ p.Position }}, {% else %}{{ p.Position }}{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Or, a more condensed version (I like this way better as it's simple):

```
{% for e in data.Employers %}
    <h3>
        {{ e.PositionsHeld | join(',', attribute="Position") }}
    </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `loop.last`! Nice! This really shows the power of Jinja2! Thank you. U+1F92F !

Comment: You're quite welcome, and yes, Jinja is very powerful.